# Check if url that is set by link isset

Tags: php

Been trying to solve this for days and just don't know what I'm doing wrong.

In the if-statement I'm checking `if $_GET['orderBy']` is set, which it is when a link I clicked. And I'm also checking if the value that is equal to orderBy is equal to a value in the array `$orderBy`, which also is true.

But the if-statement doesn't get executed, why is that ?

```
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-condensed'>
              <tr>
                  <th></th>
                  <th><a href='?orderBy=service_id'>#</a></th>
                  <th><a href='?orderBy=efternamn'>Efternamn</a></th>
                  <th><a href='?orderBy=fornamn'>Förnamn</a></th>
                  <th><a href='?orderBy=datum'>Datum</a></th>
                  <th><a href='?orderBy=reg_av'>Registrerat av</a></th> 
              </tr>";

$orderBy = array('service_id', 'efternamn', 'fornamn', 'datum' ,'reg_av');
$order = 'datum';

if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
    $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
    echo "Order by ". $order;
}else{

    echo "Order by ". $order;
} 


$query = 'SELECT service.*, kunder.fornamn, kunder.efternamn 
        FROM service_test 
        JOIN kunder ON service.kund_id=kunder.id 
        WHERE service.utford_datum != 0000-00-00
        ORDER BY '.$order;

$result = $connect->query($query);
mysqli_close($connect); 

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo"No posts found";
}else{ 

    while($result_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo "<tr>
                <td>
                    <form action='service_open.php' method='GET'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='vill_editera_service' value='1'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='service_id' value='" . $result_rs['service_id'] . "'>
                        <input type='hidden' name='kund_id' value='" . $result_rs['kund_id'] . "'>
                        <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' value='Öppna'>
                    </form>
                </td>
                <td>" . $result_rs['service_id'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $result_rs['efternamn'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $result_rs['fornamn'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $result_rs['datum'] . "</td> 
                <td>" . $result_rs['reg_av'] . "</td>
            </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table> \n";

}
```

EDIT:
Also tested by just running this code:

```
$testing = $_GET['orderBy'];
echo $testing;'
```

But it doesn't work either. I get the error message:
Notice: Undefined index:

```
orderBy in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/VP-projekt/include/inc.servicelist.php on line 17
```

Could the problem lie within XAMPP?

EDIT #2:
This is the html code

```
<?php
include_once 'includes/db_connect.php';
include_once 'includes/functions.php';
sec_session_start(); ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/my_css.css" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "include/inc.servicelist.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#pagaende").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
        type: "GET",
        url: "include/inc.garantiservice.php",             
        dataType: "html",   //expect html to be returned                
        success: function(response){                    
            $("#garanti").html(response); 
            //alert(response);
        }
    });
 $('#myTabs a:first').tab('show');
    $("#sortedtable").tablesorter({ sortlist: [0,0] });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<?php if (login_check($mysqli) == true) : ?>
<?php include("include/inc.menu.php") ?>
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Pågående arbetsordrar</h1>
</div> <!-- row -->


<div id="myTabs" class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
<li role="presentation"><a href="#bokade" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Bokade</a></li>
<li role="presentation"><a href="#garanti" aria-controls="profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Garanti</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="tab-content">
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="bokade">
    <div id="pagaende" align="center"></div>
</div>
<div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="garanti"></div>
    <div id="garanti" align="center"></div>
</div>

</div>
<?php else : ?>
    <p>
        <span class="error">You are not authorized to access this page.         </span> Please <a href="index.php">login</a>.
    </p>
<?php endif; ?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I have two questions. 1. What does `isset($_GET['orderBy'])` return? 2. What does `in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy))` return?

Comment: I have run your code upto `if-else` statement and it is working correctly.It is excuting  `if-else` statement. and please close `<table>` tag.

Comment: Hmmm... doesn't work for me. I've closed the <table> tag, I left out the last part of the code as I didn't think it was important for my question. But I have edited my question now with the rest of the code.

Comment: Could you post the entire code?

Comment: Now I also added the html code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just use

```
$order = isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy) ? $_GET['orderBy'] : 'datum';
echo "Order by ". $order;
```

I suspect that your `in_array()` condition is returning false. Make sure that returns a value of `true`.

Also, try to `echo` your `table` after you are done setting the value of `$order`.

Comment: No. It doesn't work....I also tried without checking the array: $order = isset($_GET['orderBy']) ? $_GET['orderBy'] : 'datum'; But that doesn't work either...

Comment: Mark your answer as correct as it's working. My original code also worked. The problem was with the ajax call. When I removed it it works perfectly. Now I just have to figure out a way to use both :-)

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your db and code like this:

```
<?
echo "<table class='table table-hover table-condensed'>
          <tr>
              <th></th>
              <th><a href='?orderBy=service_id'>#</a></th>
              <th><a href='?orderBy=efternamn'>Efternamn</a></th>
              <th><a href='?orderBy=fornamn'>Förnamn</a></th>
              <th><a href='?orderBy=datum'>Datum</a></th>
              <th><a href='?orderBy=reg_av'>Registrerat av</a></th> 
          </tr>";

$orderBy = array('service_id', 'efternamn', 'fornamn', 'datum' ,'reg_av');
$order = 'datum';

if (isset($_GET['orderBy']) && in_array($_GET['orderBy'], $orderBy)) {
    $order = $_GET['orderBy'];
    echo "Order by ". $order;
}else{

    echo "Order by ". $order;
} 


$query = 'SELECT service.*, kunder.fornamn, kunder.efternamn 
    FROM service 
    JOIN kunder ON service.kund_id=kunder.id 
    WHERE service.datum != 0000-00-00
    ORDER BY '.$order;

echo '<br>'.$query.'<br>';

$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "myuser", "mypass", "basteldb");
if ($connect->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
}

$result = $connect->query($query);
if (!$result) {echo "DB error";}

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0){
    echo"No posts found";
}else{ 

    while($result_rs=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo "<tr>
            <td>
                <form action='service_open.php' method='GET'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='vill_editera_service' value='1'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='service_id' value='" . $result_rs['service_id'] . "'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='kund_id' value='" . $result_rs['kund_id'] . "'>
                    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' value='Öppna'>
                </form>
            </td>
            <td>" . $result_rs['service_id'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $result_rs['efternamn'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $result_rs['fornamn'] . "</td>
            <td>" . $result_rs['datum'] . "</td> 
            <td>" . $result_rs['reg_av'] . "</td>
        </tr>";
    }
    echo "</table> \n";

}

mysqli_close($connect); 

?>
```

and it works... (changed the tablename to service and datum column name to datum and added some checks)

Comment: Can't se the changes? Still looks like the same code as I use. The table name isn't changed and  the datum column name isn't changed either.